# how to rename menu in vtiger crm am trying to do that am getting warnings

Tags: php, vtiger

I am trying to rename the menu items in v tiger crm. I googled but I could not get the right information. I try to change the menu items and getting the following warnings.

`'contacts'=>'customers' in include/language/en_us.lang.php`

``` Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ``vtigercrm/include/language/en_us.lang.php:1) in vtigercrm/index.php on line 606 ```

``` Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ``/vtigercrm/include/language/en_us.lang.php:1) in vtigercrm/index.php on line 608 ```

``` Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started ``at/vtigercrm/include/language/en_us.lang.php:1) in vtigercrm/index.php on line 610 ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

ob_start (); and ob_flush();

in your index.php and en_us.lang.php pages the problem will solve.

Answer (score 0):

1- that error states there is a blank line before the opening php statement or 2- you may save en_us.lang.php in utf8 format.

solution:

> for 1: remove any extra line(s) before `<?php` and Also after `?>` at the beginning and the end of
>   mentioned file.
>  for 2: use notepad++ to convert encoding to
>   **UTF8 without BOM** and then save it.

Comment: i don't have extra line(s) before <?php

Comment: And all the contents are in ANSI? if the answer is yes check that there is no line or space after ?> at the end of the file.

Comment: in that page no space and no line after ?>.

Comment: My opinion: recover your file (I hope you have a copy of vtiger). if the problem persists, the problem is not related to this file, Otherwise this time edit the file by another editor. I prefere notepad++

Comment: So before recovering ope np++, go to edit => preferences, in New Document/Default Directory, on the left bottom side encoding, select UTF8 without BOM radio button and **check apply to opened ANSI files** now you npp++ is ok. recover your file and open it, remember that you should have not to open correct(unchanged) file before changing npp++ configuration. Good Luck!